# "Recaptcha wasn't succesful", but works when I test it (V3, Mautic)

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, mautic

I installed reCAPTCHA V3 in [mautic](/questions/tagged/mautic) to add [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha) to my forms (as on [this page](https://www.miqipo.com/contact)). When I test it, everything seems to work fine, even in incognito mode.

But now I see that random users (definitely not bots) are getting an error message 'reCAPTCHA wasn't succesful' when they try to sumbit. I enabled score validation in Mautic with a minimum score of 0.6.

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong? Or can anyone tell me how I could debug this? I'm not at all a tech-guy.

Thank you in advance,
Jarne

I tried resetting the form and test the form in incoginto mode and on mobile device. It worked without a problem and the form details were visible in the mautic backend. But apparently it's not working for random people trying to fill in the form.

Answer (score 0):

User faces issue If the form is submitted before reCAPTCHA gets loaded on webpage then backend will be receiving the request without google token. This happens when user is facing bad internet. You can avoid this by disabling submit button until the token gets loaded